# How to customize Twitter Bootstrap from Illustrator design

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, adobe-illustrator

I'm working on a new web app and I'd like to create my GUI mockups in Illustrator then implement them in HTML5 and CSS3 using Twitter Bootstrap. I know how to use the CSS classes to create my pages but I'd like to know the process of customizing Twitter Bootstrap to match my mockups as much as possible. I'm talking about colors, typography, margins, padding, borders, button styles and so on. I'd like to create completely different themes for this and every future project I'll be working on.

I'm a programmer but I love GUI design too so I'd like to know how professional designers make all the pieces fit in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the most out of Bootstrap (especially the new "mobile first" features) I recommend using your Illustrator file as a jumping off point, rather than a spec.

I agree with the other commenter who suggested leaving the Bootstrap file in place and writing a second file with selective overrides. This is much easier with Bootstrap 3 since the flat design means less to clobber with your own declarations.

I always start with laying out a static version of the pages using plain Bootstrap then methodically cherry picking styles using the inspector (e.g. body backgrounds, typography, colors) in priority order as they stand out to me visually. I usually wind up with something that is close, but slightly different (often better), than the original design.

Good luck! If you don't fight it too hard, Bootstrap offers a lot out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap but the general consensus seems to be to leave the actual Bootstrap.css intact and create different CSS files to override Bootstrap. For example in this snippet (SCSS by the way) I commented a section as "General" and placed some default overrides for my site. Most notably would be the restyled input boxes from rounded to square.

```
/********
GENERAL
*********/
html, body {
        height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    a {
        color: #FF4329;
        &:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
    input[type="text"], .btn {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

Also note that you can [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) the files you download from Bootstrap so if you plan on using on the the grid system then that's all you need to download.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to use the grid system of Bootstrap, there're plugins for Photoshop and Illustrator that create guidelines for you (you can even specify the padding, number of columns and margin).

Bootstrap is based on CSS. When you design something in Illustrator, you'll have to export assets like images but it's important to make use of CSS also for the **most things you can**. Remember, it's faster to apply a CSS background-color instead of using an image for that purpose as background-image.

I make my scratches on paper and pass right away to html. With chrome developer tools you can easily change the css styles applied, apply new rules, etc